# How do I give a jQuery Element a fixed position on the page? In other words absolute positioning of a jQuery element

Tags: jquery, positioning, css-position, offset

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

 $('a.StackedSystem').hover(function(e) {
  var html = '<div id="StackedSysteminfo">';
  html +=    '<div id="StackedSystemTxt">

    ETTER utilizes the latest technologies for our booster systems, including PLC-Based controls complete with touch-screen panel user interfaces (HMI). The base package includes the gray scale screen as shown; color screens are also available. The PLC not only provides a cleaner interface but provides additional features like automatic logging and time/date stamping of all alarms and shut-downs. 
    Great for trouble-shooting.</div>';

  html +=  '</div>';    
  $('body').append(html).children('#info').hide().fadeIn(400);
 }, function() {
  $('#StackedSysteminfo').remove();
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [jQuery UI Position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/), and elaborate on your question. Which element(s)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('element').css({"position":"absolute","top":15,"left":10 });
```

In this example you would be positioning the element 15 px from the top of the page and 10px from the left of the page.

**EDIT**

Then you could change `absolute` above to `relative` and make sure the wrapper is absolutely or relatively positioned.

Comment: what is i wanted it positioned relative to a Wrapper that my page is contained in.